# Correctly displaying text in QGIS that is sourced from a PostGIS database

Tags: qgis, postgis

Long time listener, first time caller...

I have an issue with displaying the text that is called from a PostGIS 2.4 database into QGIS 2.16.1.

The text is displaying in the table like so; {ACACIA AVENUE} but when it displays in QGIS it does so like; {"ACACIA AVENUE"}.

To resolve this I have labelled this column using the following in the 'Label with' box in Layer Properties using substr:

```
CASE WHEN  "streetType" = 'Numbered Street' THEN concat("nationalRoadCode", ' ', substr( "name",3,((length("name")-4)))) ELSE substr( "name",3,((length("name")-4))) END
```

Which works absolutely fine and ACACIA AVENUE displays as it should!!

However, I subsequently find that where there is a single street name in this particular column it is called across into QGIS like this; {MERESIDE} so when this is labelled using the code above it comes out as ERESID!

I would rather resolve this issue using styling as opposed to altering the table as this would mean something else to do when the table is refreshed with CoU.

So my question is, how can I display both the double word texts and single word texts without losing the leading and trailing characters?

Comment: Do you have the brackets {} stored in your PostgreSQL data?

Comment: You could probably do it in with regular expression (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression if you are not familiar with the concept)

Comment: Hi Heikki, yes, all the character varying columns contain text inside these braces.